# Sierpinski carpets with steps until 5 inside a 1024 mesh grid with the same dimension

Tags: matlab, fractals

I want to generate Sierpinski carpets with steps from 1 to 5 but with the same dimension inside a 1024 by 1024 mesh grid. In my code below, i was able to generate my Sierpinski carpets but the dimensions are not the same. Take for example for **i = 1**, the whole carpet is very small compared to **i = 5**. Can someone help me improve my code? Thanks in advance!

```
    function carpet(i);
    for i = 1:5;

    M = 0;
    for k=1:i
        M = [M,        M,      M;
             M, ones(3^(k-1)), M;
             M,        M,      M];
    end

    imagesc(M);
    colormap(gray);

    axis equal;
    axis off;


    imwrite(M,[num2str(i),'_Sierpinski_carpet.bmp'])

    end
```

Comment: "the whole carpet is very small compared to **i = 5**"... that's the whole point of the algorithm you're using. It starts with a small carpet and uses multiple copies of it to build the next iteration of the carpet. If you want different behavior, you'll have to find a different algorithm altogether.

Comment: Hi. I get the concept of this kind of fractal. My question was not about the behavior of the Sierpinski carpet. What I do want to ask is about making the dimensions of the generated carpets the same in such a way that I could observe how those 'squares' inside the carpets vary their sizes as the steps increases. I'll edit my question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: If you simply want to display/save the images at a different size, I suggest you [resize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) them (probably with nearest-neighbor interpolation). Note that 1024 is not divisible by 3, so it might not be the best target size.